# Blackscreen while installing 12.10

Tags: installation, 12.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Everytime I try to install ubuntu 12.10 on my laptop i get a blackscreen after clicking on `install ubuntu`, `try ubuntu without installation` or `ubuntu live`.

I tried it with `nomodeset`, `nolapic` and `acpi=off` too but nothing works. Sometimes i even get so a loading screen with nothing but `Ubuntu 12.10` and 4 dots in the middle, after that shortly a blackscreen appears with some text on it and then the complete blackscreen appears. As i tried with "no splash" instead of "quiet splash" it shows me something with graphic and determined in it but it was to fast away in a blackscreen to remember.

Has someone any idea what I can do to get this working?

Comment: Are you sure about it? It sometimes takes very long time to start live session. Wait few minutes after selecting this option. If it didn't help you may have problem with your CD

Comment: tryed it with several cds and usb stick and even played games while waiting ~ half an hour of waiting each try so thats doesn't help me sry

Answer (score 0):

See here the description of this problem :

[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-12-10-stucks-in-a-login-loop)

I think it is because of `light-dm` it is set prior to `gdm`? - I dont know
why it is prior to `gdm`.